# Exclude weekends in $smarty.now dates

Tags: php, datetime, smarty, strtotime

I want add X days depending to date of week.
My variable is working just now with the code:

```
{$order.details.order_date|replace:'/':'-'|cat:' +8 days'|date_format:'%A, %e de %B del %Y'}
```

I want if the days are Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday and Thursday incresase 8 days and with the previous code it works, but for friday and saturday i want add 10 days, and for sunday 9 days. It is not working, it seem to read just the last code {if $Delivery_day > 0 && $Delivery_day < 5}

```
{assign var="Delivery_day" value=$smarty.now|date_format:"%u"}
    {if $Delivery_day == 7} *// sunday
        {$order.details.order_date|replace:'/':'-'|cat:' +9 days'|date_format:'%A, %e de %B del %Y'}
    {/if}
    {if $Delivery_day == 5} *// friday
        {$order.details.order_date|replace:'/':'-'|cat:' +10 days'|date_format:'%A, %e de %B del %Y'}
    {/if}
    {if $Delivery_day == 6} *// saturday
        {$order.details.order_date|replace:'/':'-'|cat:' +10 days'|date_format:'%A, %e de %B del %Y'}
    {/if}
    {if $Delivery_day > 0 && $Delivery_day < 5} *//monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday
        {$order.details.order_date|replace:'/':'-'|cat:' +8 days'|date_format:'%A, %e de %B del %Y'}
    {/if}
```

Note: Your code should be work in .tpl file, smarty and php8

Comment: add an **else** piece to your code, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47058913/nested-if-else-in-smarty for an example.

Comment: sorry, with elseif is not working, only take the value of delivery_day == 5 (friday) for all orders

Comment: Is the var that is not working: {assign var="Delivery_day" value=$smarty.now|date_format:"%u"}

Comment: Please use [edit] to **add** the code your tried using, else and/or elseif, because "not working" is a pretty vague description.

Comment: Now I understand why it doesn't work, the logic is wrong, with value=$smarty.now it is capturing the current date When I need capture the date of {$order.details.order_date}. How can i capture the weekdays (working days) of {$order.details.order_date} ?